# Failed to use Injection point in rest service

Tags: tomcat, cdi, jersey-2.0, weld

```
    public class ApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
              @Override
              protected void configure() {

          bind(AuthenticationTokenService.class).to(AuthenticationTokenService.class);
             }
        }
    }
```

This is registration resources into Jersey.

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JerseyConfig  extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {

        packages("com.skillsimprover.restexamples.rest");
        register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
        register(new ApplicationBinder());

    }
}
```

This is managed bean

```
 @ApplicationScoped
public class AuthenticationTokenService {

       @Inject
      private SysLang locale;

    @Inject
    @Configurable( "authentication.jwt.validFor" )
    private Long validFor;

    @Inject
    @Configurable( "authentication.jwt.refreshLimit" )
    private Integer refreshLimit;

    @Inject
    private AuthenticationTokenIssuer tokenIssuer;

    @Inject
    private AuthenticationTokenParser tokenParser;

    public String issueToken(String username, Set<Authority> authorities) {
        String id = generateTokenIdentifier();

          ZonedDateTime issuedDate = ZonedDateTime.now();

        ZonedDateTime expirationDate = calculateExpirationDate(issuedDate);

        AuthenticationTokenDetails tokenDetails = new AuthenticationTokenDetails();

        tokenDetails.setId(id);
        tokenDetails.setUsername(username);
        tokenDetails.setAuthorities(authorities);
        tokenDetails.setIssuedDate(issuedDate);
        tokenDetails.setExpirationDate(expirationDate);
        tokenDetails.setRefreshCount(0); 
        tokenDetails.setRefreshLimit(refreshLimit);

        return tokenIssuer.issueToken(tokenDetails);
    }
    public AuthenticationTokenDetails parseToken(String token) {
        return tokenParser.parseToken(token);
    }


    public String refreshToken(AuthenticationTokenDetails currentTokenDetails) {

        if (!currentTokenDetails.isEligibleForRefreshment()) {

            MessageException tokenCannotRefreshed = MessageException.TOKEN_CANNOT_REFRESHED;
            final String messageException = getMessageExceptionSys(tokenCannotRefreshed, locale.getLang());

            throw new AuthenticationTokenRefreshmentException(messageException);
        }

        ZonedDateTime issuedDate = ZonedDateTime.now();

        ZonedDateTime expirationDate = calculateExpirationDate(issuedDate);

        AuthenticationTokenDetails newTokenDetails = new AuthenticationTokenDetails();

        newTokenDetails.setId(currentTokenDetails.getId());
        newTokenDetails.setUsername(currentTokenDetails.getUsername());
        newTokenDetails.setAuthorities(currentTokenDetails.getAuthorities());
        newTokenDetails.setIssuedDate(issuedDate);

        newTokenDetails.setExpirationDate(expirationDate);
         newTokenDetails.setRefreshCount(currentTokenDetails.getRefreshCount() + 1);
        newTokenDetails.setRefreshLimit(refreshLimit);



        return tokenIssuer.issueToken(newTokenDetails);
    }

    private Long validFor2 = this.validFor;

    private ZonedDateTime calculateExpirationDate(ZonedDateTime issuedDate) {

        System.out.println(validFor2);
        return issuedDate.plusSeconds(validFor);
    }

    private String generateTokenIdentifier() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

This is EndPoint

```
@Provider
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Path("auth")
public class AuthenticationResource {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;

    @Inject
    private AuthenticationTokenService authenticationTokenService;


    private static final String VIEW_URL = "/WEB-INF/pages/home.html";

    @POST
    @PermitAll
    @Path("username")
    public Response authenticateUserName(UserCredentials credentials,     
    @Context HttpServletRequest request)  {

        UsernamePasswordValidator usernamePasswordValidator = new  
       UsernamePasswordValidator();
        usernamePasswordValidator.validateUsername(credentials, request);

     ....
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Jersey -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.rest.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--CDI-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.rest.version}</version>
            </dependency>


        <!-- Jackson modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JJWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java EE-->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlets.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

This the class SysLang

```
@Dependent
public class SysLang {
    private static String lang;

    static {
        Locale localeDefault = Locale.getDefault();

        lang = localeDefault.getLanguage();
    }

    public SysLang() {
    }

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

}
```

This is class that management with CDI-container.

The library "Weld" implements specification CDI. All Java beans that I installed with specific annotation (from Scope types) must be is managed with CDI-container the library "Weld".
 But injection points and produces-methods do not work, once I start from the customer side to send ajax-queries to rest-services, that is, , to the class 
AuthenticationResource

The desired component is not injected here. I get errors...

> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.logErrors The following warnings
>   have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
>   MultiException stack 1 of 7
>   org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no
>   object available for injection at
>   SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=SysLang,parent=AuthenticationTokenService,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1585822177)    at
>   org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)

Why? 
Please explain to me how correct this and why appeared this errors

I executed this:

```
public class ApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(SysLang.class).to(SysLang.class);
      bind(AuthenticationTokenService.class).to(AuthenticationTokenService.class);
    }
}
```

and i get as result

> Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [com.skillsimprover.restexamples.rest.jersey.common.registrationconfig.JerseyConfig]
>   in context with path [] threw exception
>   [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>
> com.skillsimprover.restexamples.rest.jersey.security.service.token.
>   AuthenticationTokenService.
>   calculateExpirationDate(AuthenticationTokenService.java:194)

That is not work produces-methods, that supply data.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigurationProducer {

    private Properties properties;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        properties = new Properties();
        String path = "/application.properties";

        try(InputStream stream = ConfigurationProducer.class.getResourceAsStream(path)) {

            if (stream == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find application.properties configuration file.");
            }
            this.properties.load(stream);

        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Configuration file cannot be loaded.");
        }
    }

    @Produces
    @Configurable
    public String produceString(InjectionPoint ip) {

        return getStrProperty(ip);
    }

    @Produces
    @Configurable
    public Integer produceInteger(InjectionPoint ip) {

        return Integer.valueOf(getStrProperty(ip));
    }

    @Produces
    @Configurable
    public Long produceLong(InjectionPoint ip) {

        return Long.valueOf(getStrProperty(ip));
    }

    @Produces
    @Configurable
    public Boolean produceBoolean(InjectionPoint ip) {

        return Boolean.valueOf(getStrProperty(ip));
    }



    private String getStrProperty(InjectionPoint ip){

        String key = getKey(ip);

        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }


    private String getKey(InjectionPoint ip) {

        Annotated annotated = ip.getAnnotated();
        Configurable annotation = annotated.getAnnotation(Configurable.class);

        return annotation.value();
    }
}
```

The Authenticationresource class uses annotations @Produces and @Inject, HK2 does not understand how to proceed??

Weld also uses the same annotations. How to be?

Comment: Where is `SysLang` supposed to be coming from? That's what the error is about. You bound the AuthenticationTokenService to HK2, but not the SysLang

Comment: The library "Weld" implements specification CDI. All Java beans that I installed specific annotation (from Scope types) must be with CDI-container the library "Weld".
 But injection points and produces-methods do not work, once I start from the customer side to send ajax-queries to rest-services, that is, , to the class 
AuthenticationResource

Comment: SysLang  is managed bean such as the class AuthenticationTokenService.